# How to open a file given its absolute path in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

This Python code is generating a FileNotFoundError:

```
path = prog = os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep) 
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '...\\logFiles\\logDump.txt'),"a")
```

I receive this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Root\\svn\\trunk\\src\\test\\python\\...\\logFiles\\logDump.txt'
```

C:\Root\svn\trunk\src\test\python\logFiles\logDump.txt definitely exits. What's going on with the elipsis? If I remove it, I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\logFiles\\logDump.txt'
```

It seems like something's wrong with the String I'm eventually passing to open(), but I'm not sure what it should look like. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: what's with the `...` in your path ?

Comment: I'm not really sure. If I leave it, I get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Root\\svn\\trunk\\src\\test\\python\\...\\logFiles\\logDump.txt', but if I remove it I get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\logFiles\\logDump.txt'. I'm not sure why it doesn't concatenate without that.

Comment: I believe it is necessary for os.path.join() to concatenate the beginning of the path to the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want this:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..\\logFiles\\logDump.txt')
```

which would equivalent to this:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'logFiles\\logDump.txt')
```

Or you might simply want this (it is not clear from your question):

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logFiles\\logDump.txt')
```

Comment: f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'logFiles\\logTextSuperDump.txt'),"a") produces

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Root\\svn\\trunk\\src\\test\\logFiles\\logDump.txt'

This seems really close to correct. Am I using the wrong "\\" character?

Comment: C:\Root\svn\trunk\src\test\logFiles\logDump.txt

Comment: That file doesn't exist. I'm missing one intermediate directory.

Comment: OK this answer is correct, but I did not notice that C:\\Root\\svn\\trunk\\src\\test\\logFiles\\logDump.txt was missing one directory after the change in code, C:\\Root\\svn\\trunk\\src\\test\\python\\logFiles\\logDump.txt does exist. Once I changed the code to read f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'python\\logFiles\\logDump.txt'),"a"), it ran beautifully. Thanks :)

Comment: If you are having to put the `python` back in, then use the third example which removes one less directory from the file path.